# lynx for suse Linux enterprise 10

Tags: suse, lynx

Where can I find Lynx for Suse Linux Enterprise 10?
All I can find is Lynx for OpenSuse.

Answer (score 1):

SLED/SLES is built from OpenSuSE.  For SLED/SLES 11, use packages built for OpenSuSE 11.1:

I found `lynx` while searching http://software.opensuse.org/search.

**lynx**

- x86_64: [lynx-2.8.6-143.13.x86_64.rpm](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/11.1/standard/x86_64/lynx-2.8.6-143.13.x86_64.rpm)
- i586: [lynx-2.8.6-143.12.i586.rpm](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/11.1/standard/i586/lynx-2.8.6-143.12.i586.rpm)
- src: [lynx-2.8.6-143.12.src.rpm](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/11.1/standard/src/lynx-2.8.6-143.12.src.rpm)

Add the appropriate repository to your Software Sources in `yast`.

Then search for `lynx` in your Software Installation in `yast` and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Lynx is a text-based web browser. Just install the one you found; it'll work.